# Can we create a look up field on Salesforce files object looking up to FeedItem?

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed

Can I Create a lookup relation on Salesforce Fiels object and lookup to feeditem object. Is it possible. I tried to create one but i don't see feeditem in the list of objects available to lookup.

Any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create lookup on salesforce files to FeedItem.

You can create text field of 18 characters length and store feed item id.